# Howto pass CurrentPage data when Virtual scrolling is enabled?

Tags: kendo-ui

I am using Kendo UI data Grid for displaying a large local data set (60MB). I enabled Virtual scrolling. Since the server is sending a very large dataset the performance is very low. I would like to do paging at the server end and send only a smaller data set. For this, how can I pass the currentpage data when virtual scrolling is enabled ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution to the above is : Define the controller action with below signature

public JsonResult (int skip, int take, int page, int pageSize, List sort)

Kendo Grid posts the skip, take, page, pageSize parameters based on the pageSize property of the Kendo Grid. Also Kendo grid expects total item count as part of the data returned from the action for paging to work correctly. Include TotalRowCount in the data returned and specify this in the schema property of teh DataSource. For eg.,

schema: { data: "Data", total: "TotalRowCount" }